# Should we test add/edit/delete at CakePHP?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, addition, cakephp-2.0

Should we test add/edit and delete functions created with Cake bake command?
Should we check them too? Or we have to assume they work well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to test every aspect of your app, even auto-generated functions like those on bake. However, this doesn't mean you need to test things that already have tests (i.e., core functionality).

A good reason for this is that if you end up changing that code down the road, and the test fails, you are immediately aware of it and can fix it. This avoids having to remember what you have and haven't written tests for.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, i am having problems dealing with redirects after save or delete and that stuff... :S

Comment: With Cake 2, use `ControllerTestCase` and it will mock the response sending. You can also mock other actions really easily using it.

Comment: You mean, class CommentsControllerTestCase extends ControllerTestCase {...
I am already using it.

Comment: Oh, good. Then you could mock the redirect() action from there, if you wanted to. Although you shouldn't be redirected because the response's send methods are automatically mocked for you.

Comment: So what should i do ? How can i detect it has been redirected after the testAction call?

Comment: Check `$this->headers`. The headers that would have been sent will be in there.